# How does this Dense layer calculate its dimension?

Tags: tensorflow

```
layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, input_shape=(None, 5))
x = layer(tf.zeros([10,5]))
```

x is [10,10] matrix. Why is that? Why isn't it [10,5]? It seems internally it executes [10,5] * [5,10].

How does the Dense layer has a shape of [5,10]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in an input of shape `(None, 5)`

Then you have a dense layer with 10 units. This dense layer have two sets of trainable parameters.

```
kernel => A (5,10) Matrix
bias => A (10) vector
```

The dense layer know the correct shape to construct because, you're passing the `input_shape` parameter.

Then when you call `layer(tf.zeros([10,5]))`, it does the following computation.

`matmul(input[10,5], kernel[5, 10]) + bias[1, 10] => x[10,10]`

So as you can see, it results in a `[10,10]` matrix.

Comment: @ Thushv89, how did you get the kernel A (5,10)?

Comment: If you look at the code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1cf0898dd4331baf93fe77205550f2c2e6c90ee5/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py#L1020) you can see that the `kernel` is defined using the last dimension of the input shape and number of units you defined. You are passing `input_shape=(5,)` and `Dense(10)` which enables the `Dense` layer to define the kernel as `(5, 10)`.

Comment: I see. So input_shape=(5,) is the same as input_shape=(None, 5)? Basically it means a vector of 5 features, right?

Comment: @ling Exactly. Keras automatically adds that `None` dimension when you specify the `input_shape` argument.